# How can I prevent Windows 10 from ever making my wired network connection's profile public?

Tags: windows-10, networking

I have a Win10 (v2004) system that hosts DHCP services for my home. Because of this, it's configured with a static IP on the ethernet adapter. For some reason, every few days, the adapter is switched to a Public profile and the firewall blocks DHCP services, knocking the whole house offline.

I've found plenty of questions about how to set a connection's network profile using the registry or Powershell. I don't want to fix it when it breaks, I want it to stop breaking. I would settle for a) totally disabling whatever "feature" keeps making the change, or b) fixing the network location detection service so that it can recognize the network it's connected to all the time, consistently.

Comment: The Ethernet Adapter should not switch. My own Windows 10 desktop has maintained Private LAN connection for over 4 years. Do you have Network Discovery ON (should be on so other computers can see it)?  That is important.

Comment: Yes, network discovery is turned on. I think it switches because it keeps thinking the "network" it's plugged into has changed, for whatever definition of "network" they use. Nothing actually changes, of course, but if the AP it's plugged into reboots, suddenly something is different enough that it thinks it's on a new LAN.

Comment: hi, see if it's helpful to you: https://www.zubairalexander.com/blog/how-to-switch-the-network-profile-from-public-to-private-on-windows-10/

Comment: Thanks Gloria, but as far as I can see those are all ways to change the setting once, which I already know how to do.  I'm trying to prevent Network Location Awareness from changing my Network Profile in the first place, because it happens in the background and I don't notice until stuff stops working.